# Can I use non shortcircuit logical operator in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

```
val myBoolean = false & true
```

gives a compilation error in Kotlin (Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line))

Comment: Are you talking about the infix `and` function? https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-boolean/and.html

Comment: @UnholySheep that's exactly it. You can put your comment as an answer so that I choose it as the expected answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "operator" you are looking for is the infix `and` function in Kotlin (reference page: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-boolean/and.html)
Therefore your example should be

```
val myBoolean = false and true
```